# Is it possible to generate gradient using css2?

Tags: css

Is it possible to generate gradient using css2?

Note:- Without background image

Comment: Why do you need to use CSS 2 ?

Comment: What browser and browser version are you targeting?

Answer (score 2):

No.
Using plain CSS, only in CSS3, but you may find this usefull:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It generates gradients compatible with lot of different browsers. You just have to paste the generated CSS to your sheets. **This way you don't need to load images on your background.**

Comment: I see an SVG `background-image` solution. Although the OP doesn't want it, it is indeed the only way in CSS2...

Comment: Well, I corrected the "No and yes", but what I understood is that he don't want existing images to me loaded as background.

Comment: The `filter` attribute is supported by IE all the way back to 5.5. Using this tool is my preferred method, although I have a LESS mixin that automagically injects the browser prefixes and adds `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but here is the best cross-browser approach:

```
background-color: #ccc; // If gradients are not supported by browser

background-image:         linear-gradient( bottom, #ccc 0%, #ddd 100% );
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( bottom, #ccc 0%, #ddd 100% );
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( bottom, #ccc 0%, #ddd 100% );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( bottom, #ccc 0%, #ddd 100% );
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( bottom, #ccc 0%, #ddd 100% );
background-image:        -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ccc), color-stop(1, #ddd) );
```